# Problems with subclasses inheriting class factory methods (Objective-C)

Tags: objective-c

While I'm more than familiar with C#, I'm totally new at Objective C and iOS development.  So I'm learning the language.  What I don't understand is why the following code throws a compiler error (and yes, this is from the exercises at [Programming with Objective C](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithObjects/WorkingwithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH4-SW24):

**SNDPerson:**

```
@interface SNDPerson : NSObject

@property NSString *first;
@property NSString *last;

+ (SNDPerson *)person;
@end

@implementation SNDPerson
+ (SNDPerson *)person
{
   SNDPerson *retVal = [[self alloc] init];
   retVal.first = @"Ari";
   retVal.last = @"Roth";

   return retVal;
}
@end
```

**SNDShoutingPerson:**

```
#import "SNDPerson.h"

@interface SNDShoutingPerson : SNDPerson
@end

@implementation SNDShoutingPerson

// Implementation is irrelevant here; all it does is override a method that prints a string
// in all caps.  This works; I've tested it.  However, if necessary I can provide more code.
// The goal here was for a concise repro.

@end
```

**Main method:**

```
- int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
   SNDShoutingPerson *person = [[SNDShoutingPerson alloc] person];  // Error
   ...
}
```

The error is "No visible @interface for "SNDShoutingPerson" declares the selector "person".

Shouldn't this work?  SNDShoutingPerson inherits from SNDPerson, so I would have assumed it got access to SNDPerson's class factory methods.  Did I do something wrong here, or do I have to declare the method on SNDShoutingPerson's interface as well?  The exercise text implies that what I did should Just Work.

Comment: It's a class method - perhaps you don't have to alloc first - `[SNDShoutingPerson person]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Omit the `+alloc` when calling the class method:

```
SNDShoutingPerson *person = [SNDShoutingPerson person];
```

Briefly:

`+ (id)foo` denotes a **class method**. This takes the form:

```
[MONObject method];
```

`- (id)foo` denotes an **instance method**. This takes the form:

```
MONObject * object = ...; // << instance required
[object method];
```

Also, you can declare `+ (instancetype)person` in this case, rather than `+ (SNDPerson *)person;`.

Answer (score 0):

change the line `SNDShoutingPerson *person = [[SNDShoutingPerson alloc] person];`  // Error

to

```
SNDShoutingPerson *person = [[SNDShoutingPerson alloc] init];
```

Cheers.

If you want to call class method:

```
SNDPerson person = [SNDPerson person];
```

Answer (score 0):

`person` is a class method, but you're trying to call it with the incompletely constructed instance returned by alloc. Kill the alloc and just do `[SNDShoutingPerson person]`.

This has nothing to do with subclasses, by the way. You would get the same error if you had written `[[SNDPerson alloc] person]`.